# What is the name of this letter?

Tags: notation

I found the symbol below on an article, but I don't know its name.

[image: weird math symbol]

Thanks

Comment: There is a page called detexify which is great for this kind of questions.

Comment: @Integrator: I do not think you may replace original question with your interpretations. Please, put the image back.

Comment: Here is a link to [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

Comment: This is question fits better on http://tex.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: The voting on this page makes me very sad. (No offense to the users!)

Comment: Voted to reopen. I think that asking here about a confusing symbol found in mathematical literature is a perfectly fine use for the site (in fact, better than coming here to ask homework questions)...

Comment: Yes, the number of votes and views is unusual. It should probably be moved to tex.se.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is the character $$\Huge \mathfrak{X} $$ or `\mathfrak{X}`, which is just a capital X in the Fraktur typeface.